# Unknown datatype on fk reference

Tags: mysql, sql, h2

I am trying to run this mysql commands in my H2 database. The DB is set to mysql mode.

```
-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `users`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL COMMENT '     ',
  `email` VARCHAR(320) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `serverprojects`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `serverprojects` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `status` TINYINT(1) NULL,
  `restorescript_relative_path` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `backupscript_relative_path` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `installscript_relative_path` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `username` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(100) NULL,
  `gradle_relative_path` VARCHAR(255) NULL,
  `root_path` VARCHAR(1000) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `projects`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `projects` (
  `id` INT NOT NULL,
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
  `serverprojects_id` INT NOT NULL,
  `users_id` INT NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  INDEX `fk_projects_serverprojects_idx` (`serverprojects_id` ASC),
  INDEX `fk_projects_users1_idx` (`users_id` ASC),
  CONSTRAINT `fk_projects_serverprojects`
    FOREIGN KEY (`serverprojects_id`)
    REFERENCES `serverprojects` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION,
  CONSTRAINT `fk_projects_users1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`users_id`)
    REFERENCES `users` (`id`)
    ON DELETE NO ACTION
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

This produced the following error output

```
Unbekannter Datentyp: "FK_PROJECTS_SERVERPROJECTS_IDX"
Unknown data type: "FK_PROJECTS_SERVERPROJECTS_IDX"; SQL statement:
-- ----------------------------------------------------- 
-- Table `projects` 
-- ----------------------------------------------------- 
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `projects` ( 
  `id` INT NOT NULL, 
  `name` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
  `serverprojects_id` INT NOT NULL, 
  `users_id` INT NOT NULL, 
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`), 
  INDEX `fk_projects_serverprojects_idx` (`serverprojects_id` ASC), 
  INDEX `fk_projects_users1_idx` (`users_id` ASC), 
  CONSTRAINT `fk_projects_serverprojects` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`serverprojects_id`) 
    REFERENCES `serverprojects` (`id`) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION, 
  CONSTRAINT `fk_projects_users1` 
    FOREIGN KEY (`users_id`) 
    REFERENCES `users` (`id`) 
    ON DELETE NO ACTION 
    ON UPDATE NO ACTION) 
ENGINE = InnoDB [50004-193] HY004/50004 (Help)
```

Does anyone know whats going on here ? I think the problem is inside the syntax of  INDEX `fk_projects_serverprojects_idx` (`serverprojects_id` ASC), but i cant get this to work

Answer (score 0):

I just found out that the problem is this:

```
INDEX `fk_projects_serverprojects_idx` (`serverprojects_id` ASC), 
  INDEX `fk_projects_users1_idx` (`users_id` ASC),
```

in combination with the InnoDB. With InnoCb you are not alowed to do this.

Comment: I don't work with MySQL but I find it surprising that any RDBMS would allow you to index a field before it's created.